# Using foreach on a dataviewgrid in VS 2015 Pro

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to use a foreach loop with a DataGridView in VS 2015 Pro (C#) to search for a specific ID.  The example that I was able to find show using DataGridViewRow but VS 2105 does not have that,it has DataGridItem but not anything to do with the row.  When it tried foreach(DataGridItem row in gvNCAMS.Rows) I get that the system cannot cast from Row to DataGridItem.  How can I use a foreach loop for this?
I am using:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gvNCAMS.Rows) { if (row.Cells[4].Equals(iSearch)) { rowIndex = iIndex; break; } } gvNCAMS.SelectedIndex = rowIndex;
```

as my code to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
   foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
   {
      if(item.Cells["IDColumnName"].Value.ToString() == "something")
      {
          dataGridView1.Rows[item.Index].Selected = true;
      }
   }
```

Remember that a foreach loop wont allow you to change date, you can only iterate through and read it.

However, personally i would bind a datagridview to a dataset or datatable and then make the changes in those. Personally i think that is much neater and better code practise.

The namespace you will need for a `DataGridViewRow` is : `using System.Windows.Forms;`

If your messing around with "data stuff" id say it was safe to include the `using System.Data;` namespace also.

Comment: just noticed you said vs 2015 pro does not have a datagridviewrow. It certainly does, check that you are using the correct namespaces. I used the same version to write that example.

Comment: What I am actually trying to do is to search for a specific ID in the grid and set the focus on that row so I can pull the data from a database to populate another part of the form.  What namespace should I be using to get the DataGridViewRow?

Comment: @donald.dougherty Please see the updated answer. FYI you can also set focus to a single cell.

Comment: This is the code that I am using:              foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gvNCAMS.Rows)

            {

                if (row.Cells[4].Equals(iSearch))

                {

                    rowIndex = iIndex;

                    break;

                }

            }

            gvNCAMS.SelectedIndex = rowIndex; and I am getting:  {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'."} when I run it.

Comment: sorry, im a bit busy working ^^' ill take a look when i can, but from your error it looks like you are trying to use a control that doesnt actually belong to a datagridview. also you are trying to compare a Cell.Equals, you should be comparing the Cell.Value.Equals, that might be where the problem lies.

Comment: I changed DataGridViewRow to GridViewRow and I have it going through the first page of data.  Thank you, that is a step in the right direction.  I am, however, having problems getting to search subsequent pages.

Comment: can you please edit you question and show us the class of code. make sure you edit it as code so as not to anger the Stack overflow gods.

Comment: How do I edit it as code? I am still kind of new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: There are some helper context boxes that can show up when you are typing, but generally highlight the code that you type in and hit `Ctrl+K`.